# How to implement the Google Distance Matrix API in Java without using the HTTP request method

Tags: java, google-maps, google-api-java-client, google-distancematrix-api

I am aware of the fact that I am able to use a HTTP request to use the distance matrix API (i.e. `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=42.11622,78.10112&destinations=40.82231,72.224166&key=YOUR_API_KEY`)

But I would like to simply use the Java API instead. From my understanding the first step is to create a GeoApiContext and this seems to be where I am failing. I have tried the following code:

`private static GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder().apiKey("MyKey").queryRateLimit(500).build();`

However I am just met with the following compile error:

`java.land.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter`

Any help on the matter would be appreciated. The plan is to use this to create a DistanceMatrix API request if that helps.

Comment: It might also be useful to know that I am using version 0.2.2 of the Java API

Comment: It looks like [RateLimiter](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) belongs to the [Guava: Google Core Libraries for Java](https://github.com/google/guava). Did you include the guava in your project dependencies?

Comment: Checkout this answer -[Finding distance and time between two places using google distance matrix api](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48487598/7849549)

Answer (score 0):

check out this link you may find it useful... there are code examples
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.maps.model.DistanceMatrix

Comment: Thanks, this seems useful to have for after the geoApiContext has been setup, which is unfortunately the thing I am trying to first sort :(